# Agnostic default value for Boolean Types

Tags: hibernate

Our application works correctly with Hibernate 5 and PostgreSQL for boolean types which need to have a default value with the `columnDefinition = "bool default false"` property of @Column annotation.
Now we have to make the application work with Oracle and PostgreSql and we have to avoid using this columnDefinition as is not a valid value with Oracle.
¿How could we set the default value to these boolean fields?
I can't change the actual boolean type in db and use things like TrueFalseType.

The only way I've found to have a similar behavior is creating a custom converter to avoid the null values

```
@Converter
public class Converter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Boolean> {

  @Override
  public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean aBoolean) {
    return Objects.nonNull(aBoolean) && aBoolean.booleanValue();
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Boolean aBoolean) {
    return Objects.nonNull(aBoolean) && aBoolean.booleanValue();
  }
}
```

and then annotate the entity property with `@Convert(converter = Converter.class)`

I'm not sure about this solution and if there could be a better solution

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do understand that a column default only take effect if you don't list the column in an insert statement? As soon as you map a column, Hibernate will always list the column in the insert statement, so the column defaults are useless. Just assign a non-null default value to the entity field.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know what you say about default values and that I have to assign a default value. The problem is that we have clients with sql scripts that populate the database without that property and then a null value would be inserted

Comment: Well, who says that you have to use the schema that hbm2ddl generates out of the box? You can use a tool like Liquibase or Flyway to do the schema management. Together with the JPA Buddy plugin, setting up changelog is super easy.

Comment: Hi again! Yes, we have plan to use LiquidBase but not in a recent future so i have to find out some solution. I give your solution as accepted because if we had done all correctly from the begining we won't be in that situation. With this question i was wondering if my solution is a really bad solution or not at all.

Comment: What is the point of having a converter when you want to use a column default? One thing you could do is to create a function that exists on both DBs which returns a boolean for one DB and a smallint/char for the other.

Comment: The point is to treat the null values with the boolean datatype without any npe. But I see that obviously is not the better solution

Comment: Null values that are inserted by an external script who trust in that default value so now are null values.

Comment: If you have scripts that insert null, but you don't want null values, then add a trigger that sets the column to false/true if null.

Comment: Hi again Christian. Indeed that would be a good solution that i don't realized. Thanks for your time and help!!